# Install Ubuntu 14.04 / 15 in computer with Windows 8.1 Legacy installed before

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows, grub-legacy

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 to dual boot with Win 8.1 installed before.
I installed Windows 8.1 in Legacy mode, my laptop is Dell Vostro 2420 which support UEFI but I disable UEFI boot mode before install Windows. Now, when I create Ubuntu 14.04 installation in my usb by Linux Pen Drive, it's UEFI certainly which I can't change. Can I install Ubuntu in Legacy mode and how?

Comment: You could use virtualbox :3

Comment: You mean create a VirtualBox VM install ubuntu to my VM? I want Ubuntu to do something pretty heavy in windows like Netbean and Android developing :) I have 4 GB RAM only, how much I give for the VM? I don't think they will be smooth on a VM with 1GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

Legacy boot can be turned off after the install is completed - it is only for the usb boot support. UEFI boot is the problem, I'm pretty sure changing that may corrupt the win bootloader. Can't really help you there - re-install?

During the install I believe fast boot and secure boot is what you want to disable in the BIOS. I'm pretty sure I put both UEFI files in the same partition (I could be wrong) - once installed, grub will become your default boot manager.

From there you can go to Windows or Linux - sometimes you have to "fix" the grub - after major Windows updates -  I use (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and do the recommended repair option.